# Why AWS Scan LastEvaluatedKey return values even when the Key not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Why does AWS Scan LastEvaluatedKey return values ​​even when the key does not exist?

My scan request is

```
  {
  "TableName": "tks-processtracker-dumper",
  "ExclusiveStartKey": {
      "Mykey": {
          "S": "AKeyThatDoesntExists"
      }
  },
  "Limit": 2000
  }
```

Even passing a key that does not exist in the table, scanning still returns values.

My question is, should it return values ​​even when the key doesn't exist? and why?

Answer (score 1):

It's an ***EXCLUSIVE*** start key...

It doesn't have to exist, as DDB starts reading at whatever item has the next higher value.

In SQL it'd look something like

```
select *
from table
where tableKey > :exclusiveStartKey
```

Comment: I think this is a  good parallel to sql.  The exclusivestart key is just an index of where it should start scanning.

Answer (score 0):

ExclusiveStartKey is essentially a pointer to a location on the storage medium.

It doesn't care if the item is there, it hashes the value you submit and that points to a location in disk and the Scan will proceed from that position.

Comment: So it generates a hash of the key value it sends and does it like a LIKE in SQL? If the hash points to a location on disk that location shouldn't exist right? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Not quite, items are stored by the value if the hash key in DynamoDB. So when you hash the value you submit, it points to an exact location in disk. Then it just starts the Scan at that location and proceeds forward reading the rest of the remaining items after that point